# Insert an array into a field in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

```
db.createCollection("course_content_search_history",{
    validator:{
        $jsonSchema: {
            bsonType: "object",
            required: ["user_id", "course_id", "searched_date", "search_string","content_types", "offset", "count","selected_contents"],
            properties: {
                user_id: {
                    bsonType: "long",
                    description: "must be long and is required"
                },
                course_id: {
                    bsonType: "long",
                    description: "must be long and is required"
                },
                searched_date: {
                    bsonType: "long",
                    description: "must be long and is required"
                },
                search_string: {
                    bsonType: "string",
                    description: "must be string and is required"
                },
                content_types: {
                    bsonType: "string",
                    description: "must be a string and is required"
                },
                offset: {
                    bsonType: "long",
                    description: "must be long and is required"
                },
                count: {
                    bsonType: "long",
                    description: "must be long and is required"
                },
                selected_contents: {
                    bsonType: ["long"],
                    description: "must be array of long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The above is the validator I have used and below is the command I used to insert data into that collection.

```
db.course_content_search_history.insertOne({
    "user_id": NumberLong(4487),
    "course_id": NumberLong(4),
    "search_string":"mat",
    "searched_date": NumberLong(1599033206079),
    "offset": NumberLong(0),
    "count": NumberLong(10),
    "content_types": "lecture,test,video,document,interactive-session",
    "selected_contents": [
        NumberLong(399), 
        NumberLong(405), 
        NumberLong(408), 
        NumberLong(413), 
        NumberLong(400), 
        NumberLong(412), 
        NumberLong(404), 
        NumberLong(401), 
        NumberLong(403), 
        NumberLong(409)
    ]
})
```

When  tried to insert using the above statement it is throwing validation error. Couldn't understand what's the issue. I want the **selected_contents** to store only list of long values not an object. Is it even possible in mongoDB?
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after a little research. You can use:

```
properties: {
  selected_contents: {
    bsonType: 'array'
    items: {
      bsonType: 'int'
    }
  }
}
```